# Upload input form data and file/image Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, multipartform-data, formidable

I am trying to send form data life person name, email and image together using Next js. I used formdata for file upload and using `react-hook-form` for form input.
The problem is I couldn't receive the image/file in the Next api.

My codes are :

**Onchange:**

```
const handleImgChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
        const img = e.target.files[0];
        setProfileImg(img);
    }
};
```

to get form data from input.

```
const handleIChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setContents((prevContnet) => {
        return {
            ...prevContnet,
            [e.target.name]: value,
        };
    });
};
```

**On submit**

```
const handleOnsubmlit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (profileImg.length > 0) {
        const formData = { ...contents, profile_picture: profileImg };
        updateUserSetting(formData);
    } else {
        updateUserSetting(contents);
    }
};
```

**updateUserSetting**

```
async function updateUserSetting(formdata) {
    try {
        console.log("form datas", formdata);
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_USER_SETTING_REQUEST" });
        const { data } = await axios(
            `${NEXT_URL}/api/updateusersetting`,
            {
                method: "PUT",
                formdata,
                "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            }
        );
        console.log("return data ", data[0]);
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_USER_SETTING_SUCCESS", payload: data[0] });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: "UPDATE_USER_SETTING_FAIL",
            payload: error.response 
        });
    }
}
```

**API**

```
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";

 export const config = {
     api: {
         bodyParser: false,
     },
 };

export default async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === "PUT") {
        if (!req.headers.cookie) {
            res.status(403).json({ message: "Not Authorized" });
            return;
        }
        const { token } = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie);

        console.log("body is", req.body);

        const formData = await new Promise((req, res) => {
            const form = new IncomingForm();
            form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                    return;
                }
                res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" });
                res.json({ fields, files });
            });
        });
};
```

how can I put data together and send it to the desired API? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface to send files and other fields as a single JSONified string, or individual strings. Formidable will separate your fields and files in the callback, and you can process them individually.

Here's a working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-nextform-htl6j).

Output:

[image]

Comment: The codesandbox link is failure.

Comment: Restored the codesandbox link @何家華

Comment: If i have a POST menthod upload web api with "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
In Next.js how can I send file from client to Next.js API route, then send to my POST menthod upload web api ?

Comment: You can make an axios request from your next.js api to your upload api and pass your headers in the 3rd parameter of `axios.post()`.